# CSS Transition Not Returning To Original Shape & Can't Click Multiple Times

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here's the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/frankDraws/pen/KVKvwN?editors=110).

The square changes to a circle as expected when it slides to the right, but when it returns back to the left, it stays a circle instead of changing to a square.

Also, I can only click the `<a>` once. If I try to click multiple times, it doesn't work.

Trying to do this with only CSS (if possible).

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: gainsboro;
}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.path {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  x-background: white;
}
@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 95%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
.shape:target {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  animation-name: ani;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: slateblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: none;
  transition: border-radius .4s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="path">
    <a href="#elem"><span id="elem" class="shape"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get with just CSS is this, as far as I know:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: gainsboro;
}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.path {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  x-background: white;
}
@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 95%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
.path a:focus .shape {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  animation-name: ani;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: slateblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: none;
  transition: border-radius .4s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="path">
    <a href="#" tabindex="-1"><span id="elem" class="shape"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem before was triggering the state with `:target:`.  This is tough to debug with sites like Codepen or other embedded editors, since you can't see the hash change.  Basically, clicking the link would append `#elem` to the URL, apply the `:target` styles to `.shape`, and stay like that until the hash changes.

This solution uses `:focus`, which gets you closer to your goal, but not all the way.  To repeat the animation, you need to defocus/blur the circle, then click it again.

I'm usually all for CSS-only effects, but I'm pretty sure you'll need Javascript for this.  Something as simple as applying a class on click, waiting 2 seconds, then removing the class would accomplish the same effect more reliably.

Comment: Thanks @ScottKaye . I really appreciate your help.

Wasn't sure if I could get away from JS on this but I wanted to try any way. I like simplicity.

Comment: What's your purpose for adding `tabindex="-1"` on the `<a>` tag? Just curious.

Comment: I'm used to adding that attribute to force an element to be focus-able, but in this case it's not needed here.  Sorry!

Comment: No worries. I just like to know how other's code. Helps me learn. Thanks again.